# É correto no MVC acessar dados dentro da model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, design-pattern, model

Em um projeto C# MVC, é correto fazer acesso a dados dentro da *model*? Por Exemplo:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //outros atributos...

    public void Inserir(){
        Cliente c = new Cliente();

        //Outras ações

        DaoCliente dao = new DaoCliente();
        dao.InserirCliente(c);
    }
}
```

Isso é correto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De forma geral tudo o que se refere aos dados deve ser feito no modelo, ainda que indiretamente. Quaisquer operações que manipulem os dados deveriam estar no modelo.

Então o método de inserir aquele dado deve ser colocado no modelo mesmo. E pode colocar o detalhe fora dele, como foi feito neste exemplo.

Imagino que a dúvida é se o controlador deve fazer toda implementação da inserção e de forma geral não deve.

Cada um com sua responsabilidade. O controlador deve dizer o que fazer e não como fazer.

Eu não tinha prestado atenção inicialmente, mas a linha `Cliente c = new Cliente();` não faz o que imagina. Está criando outro objeto dentro do objeto que está manipulando. Isto não deve ser feito, a não ser que tenha um motivo para ter um cliente novo dentro do cliente, o que é altamente improvável.

Não é este cliente que deve usar para gravar o modelo, é o `this`.

Acho esquisito [criar um cliente novo em estado inválido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

E não me parece que esse DAO seja bem construído. Na verdade questiono o uso de DAO específico assim, mas isto é outro assunto.

Comment: A dúvida era essa mesmo. Ajudou demais. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Só uma observação, se você está com um método dentro da própria classe, não precisa instanciar um novo objeto:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //outros atributos...

    public void Inserir(){
        //Outras ações

        DaoCliente dao = new DaoCliente();
       this.Id = dao.InserirCliente(this); //Já atribui a Id que foi inserida ao objeto atual
    }
}
```

Mas eu, utilizaria de um método estático:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //outros atributos...

    public static int Inserir(Cliente c)
    {
        //Outras ações

        DaoCliente dao = new DaoCliente();
        return dao.InserirCliente(c);
    }
}
```

ou

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //outros atributos...

    public static int Inserir(string nome)
    {
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        c.Nome = nome;
        //Outras ações

        DaoCliente dao = new DaoCliente();
        return dao.InserirCliente(c); //retorna a id que foi inserida
    }
}
```

podendo ainda ser sobrecarregado.

> Sei que não é a resposta para o que foi perguntado, mas é apenas uma observação que acho válida. Espero não receber negativos por isso =]